# Delete multiple selected DataTable rows with one click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using an example from Datatables to delete rows from a table. This works fine, one by one but I need the ability to select and delete multiple rows. I commented the `//.removeClass('row_selected');` so the user is visually able to select more than one row, but still the rows only delete one at a time. Ideas?
https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/select_single_row.html

http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/22/

**jQuery**

```
var oTable;

$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Add a click handler to the rows - this could be used as a callback */
    $("#example tbody tr").click( function( e ) {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
        }
        else {
            oTable.$('tr.row_selected')//.removeClass('row_selected');
            $(this).addClass('row_selected');
        }
    });

    /* Add a click handler for the delete row */
    $('#delete').click( function() {
        var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
        if ( anSelected.length !== 0 ) {
            oTable.fnDeleteRow( anSelected[0] );
        }
    } );

    /* Init the table */
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable( );
} );


/* Get the rows which are currently selected */
function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
{
    return oTableLocal.$('tr.row_selected');
}*
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will delete multiple rows...

```
$('#delete').click( function() {
    var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
    $(anSelected).remove();
} );
```

This is preferable to using the in-built delete method in dataTables as it changed quite drastically at one point.  Initially, it would retain row indexes between deletes, so you could delete row 1, then row 2, then row 3 etc..  It was then changed so that you could delete row 1, and row 2 would *become* row 1, so you'd have to delete row 1 again etc..

Using the above method just removes the rows from the table directly, which is much easier and will save you hassle if changing versions of dataTables at any time.

**http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/23/**

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I was over thinking it. Thanks!

Comment: I used this approach to delete rows in my table but I also have an add row function. I don't know why when I add a new row after I delete multiple/single row, the deleted rows are added back to their specific positions. I hope you can help me.

Comment: @newbie Without seeing your code and knowing how you add the new row there's no way of knowing.  I suggest you ask a new question :)

Comment: doesn't work with pagination when you want to delete entries you cannot see.. :/

Comment: this fiddle example does not update the bottom table info on delete. The fiddle example below by Ganjar Setia also updates the table info on delete

Answer (score 3):

Here my version, It will delete multiple row and update data info in the footer

```
$('#delete').click( function() {
    var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );

    for (var i = 0; i < anSelected.length; i++) {
        oTable.fnDeleteRow(anSelected[i]);
    };
});
```

The Datatable have delete function row, but only 1 row. So I just looping it. The info will be updated too.

> Showing 1 to 3 of 3 entries

here my code and demo

http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/95/

Comment: doesn't work with pagination when you want to delete entries you cannot see.. :/

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

```
var oTable = new DataTable(".dataTable", {
  paging: true,
  pageLength: 10,
  responsive: true,
  select: {
    style: "multi", // Enable multi-selection
    selector: "td:first-child", // Enable selection on the first column (checkbox)
  },
  language: {
    processing: true,
    search: "Rechercher&nbsp;:",
    lengthMenu: " _MENU_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
    info: " Total&nbsp;: _TOTAL_ ",
    infoEmpty: " 0 &eacute;l&eacute;ment",
    infoFiltered: "(_MAX_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments au total)",
    infoPostFix: "",
    loadingRecords: "Chargement en cours...",
    zeroRecords: "Aucun &eacute;l&eacute;ment &agrave; afficher",
    emptyTable: "Aucune donnée disponible dans le tableau",
    paginate: {
      first: "Premier",
      previous: "Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent",
      next: "Suivant",
      last: "Dernier",
    },
    aria: {
      sortAscending: ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
      sortDescending: ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre décroissant",
    },
  },
});

// Toggle the selected class on row click
oTable.on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

// Handle multiple selection and row removal
$('#delete-selected-btn').click(function () {
    var selectedRows = oTable.rows('.selected').data();

    if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
        // Remove selected rows
        oTable.rows('.selected').remove().draw(false);
    } else {
        alert('Please first make a selection from the list.');
    }
});
```